# travesersing the dom with inexact parameters

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I want to grab the image src on a product page in a e commerce website.

I'm writing this as a bookmarklet, so I'd like the code to work universally as possible.

I've noticed that there are only two reoccurring factors in the product image tag among top e-commerce websites (amazon, bestbuy ect.): `border=0` and `180<width&height<400`.
So how could I write a selector that would give me the `src`of the first `img` element on the page with no border and width & height between 180 and 400 px? Or is there a better way of doing this?

P.S. since I'm trying to keep the bookmarklet as light as possible, I don't want to use any libraries (jquery, yui etc)

Comment: You might find that after writing all the 'pure' JavaScript you need to get this working, it ends up around the same amount as a minified jQuery plus two or three lines of your own to use it...

Comment: maybe, but at least i won't have to do the ugly jquery injection on to the page. (bookmarklet will be clicked 90% on pages that don't have jquery)

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel like I fully understand your question, but here I go anyways!

Do you mean something like...

```
function findYouImg() {
   var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
   for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
      if(imgs[i].border=='' && imgs[i].width>180 && imgs[i].height<400 ) {
         return imgs[i];
      }
   }
}
```

Or are you refering to external CSS properties when you speak of border, width and height?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to support browsers which don't implement [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate), another approach would be to look at each site you want to support, create an XPATH expression which uniquely identifies the product image and use a lookup based on the domain:

```
var productImageXPath = (function() {
  var xpaths = {
    'amazon.com': "//img[@id='prodImage']",
    'bestbuy.com': "//div[@id='imagepreview']/img"
  };
  function endsWith(s1, s2) {
    return (s1.indexOf(s2) == s1.length - s2.length);
  };
  return function(host) {
    for (attr in xpaths) {
      if (endsWith(host, attr)) {
        return xpaths[attr];
      }
    }
    return null;
  };
})();
var xpath = productImageXPath(location.host);
if (xpath) {
  var img = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  if (img) {
    console.log(img.src);
  }
}
```